# How to remove substring and comma if exist on left or right side

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

> "house,car,table"

I need to properly handle the comma removal, so much so that If I remove "car" the output should be:

> "house,table"

If I remove "table" the output should be:

> "house,car"

Comment: What are you using to remove the data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) in an array then [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) out the target text after words [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=example) to create a string.

```js
var str = "house,car,table";
str = str.split(',').filter(x => x !== 'car').join(',');

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. @Satpal has offered a way that is optimized. but another way:

```js
var array ="house,car,table";
    var arraySplit = array.split(",");
    var newArray = [];
    for (i=0; i<arraySplit.length; i++)
    {
        if (arraySplit[i] != "car")
        {
            newArray.push(arraySplit[i]);
        }
    }
    var joinedArray = newArray.join(",");

    console.log(joinedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string#split`, `string#indexOf` `array#splice` and `arr#join`

```js
var str = "house,car,table";
var arr = str.split(',');

var index = arr.indexOf('car');
arr.splice(index, 1);

console.log(arr.join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function format(name){
  var nameStr="house,car,table";
  if(nameStr.indexOf(name)==-1)return -1;
  nameStr+=",";
  nameStr=nameStr.replace(name+",","");
  return nameStr.substring(0,nameStr.length-1);
 }
 
 console.log(format("house"));
 console.log(format("table"));
```